# Spring hibernate application One to Many relationship 404

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I am trying to build an app that has to objects, book and review, a book can have multiple reviews.

I could see the list of books, but when I entered the book page I could see the title and other attributes of the book but not the attributes of the reviews.
Now i modified the code and i get a 404 error with the warning:

`WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'`

I want to mention that i don't have Set variable and method implemented in Review class.
I am using annotation and no xml file in my implementation, please help me

Review.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REVIEW")
public class Review {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;
@Column(name = "R_DATE")
private Date r_date;
@Column(name = "R_AUTHOR")
private String r_author;
@Column(name = "R_TEXT")
private String r_text;
@Column(name = "R_RATING")
private int r_rating;
@Column(name = "R_BOOKID")
@JoinColumn(name = "BOOKID", nullable = false)
private int r_bookid;

@ManyToOne
private Book book;

public Review(String author, String text, Date date, int rating, int bookid, Book book)
{   
    super();
    this.r_author = author;
    this.r_text = text;
    this.r_date = date;
    this.r_rating = rating;
    this.r_bookid = bookid;
    this.book= book;
}
...
public Book getBook() {
    return book;
}

public void setBook(Book book) {
    this.book = book;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);  

}
```

Book.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "BOOKID")
private int bookId;
@Column(name = "BOOKRATING")
private int bookRating;
@Column(name = "BOOKCATEGORY")
private String bookCategory;
@Column(name = "BOOKAUTHOR")
private String bookAuthor;
@Column(name = "BOOKTITLE")
private String bookTitle;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Review> review = new HashSet<Review>(0);

public Book(){

}

public Book(String title) 
{
    this.bookTitle = title;
}
...
public Set<Review> getReviews() {
    return review;
}
public void setReviews(Set<Review> review) {
    this.review = review;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);  

}
```

The server log:

```
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon May 04 17:01:08 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
May 04, 2015 5:01:08 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Registering annotated classes: [class com.bookr.app.config.ApplicationContextConfig]
May 04, 2015 5:01:09 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
May 04, 2015 5:01:09 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
May 04, 2015 5:01:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 04, 2015 5:01:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
May 04, 2015 5:01:10 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
May 04, 2015 5:01:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
May 04, 2015 5:01:10 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
May 04, 2015 5:01:10 PM org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator <init>
INFO: HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.bookr.app.model.Review (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
May 04, 2015 5:01:11 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@3f0938ef] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
May 04, 2015 5:01:11 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcher': initialization completed in 2577 ms
May 04, 2015 5:01:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/app] is completed
May 04, 2015 5:01:11 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'
May 04, 2015 5:01:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'
```

The controller

```
    package com.bookr.app.controller;
import com.bookr.app.dao.BookDAO;
import com.bookr.app.dao.ReviewDAO;
import com.bookr.app.model.Book;
import com.bookr.app.model.Review;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Autowired
    private BookDAO bookDao;
    @Autowired
    private ReviewDAO reviewDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView book(Locale locale)
    {
        List<Book> listBook = bookDao.list();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("book");
        model.addObject("bookList", listBook);
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale , "and the books will be listed");
        return model;
    }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/book", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView viewBook(HttpServletRequest request) {
            int bookId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            Book book = bookDao.get(bookId);
          Set<Review> review = book.getReviews();
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("viewBook");
            model.addObject("book", book);
            model.addObject("review", review);

            return model;  
     }


}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: It is not JPA/Hibernate error. Check your web.xml for mapping URI. It seems there is no mapping for /app/ pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response i used this tutorial and it says to remove web.xml file and use java files instead so i do not have a web xml file now      http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-2-java-based-configuration

Comment: If you are using annotations, then make sure you have a controller with URI mapping `/app`. For example, if you have a REST Controller, then you need something like this on top of your controller. `@RestController`
`@RequestMapping("/app")`.

Comment: I edited the post and added my controller, it's ok like this?

Comment: Based on your log `INFO: Reloading Context with name [/app] is completed` i believe your context path is `app`. If that is the case you don't need `/app` on your controller. if your dispatcher servlert is mapped to `/` then you must be able to access it as `{your doman}/app`.

Comment: The thing it doesn't work with or without the /app :( . And if i change something in mapping (the Many-To-One or One-To-Many annotations) it givev me an error that says that it doesn't know the type of the book column